# Accept cookies with CURL on PHP

Tags: php, linux, curl, cookies

I'm trying to run a log in script over my Centos machine.
What the script does is logging in with a username and password to a 3rd party site and gets the page contents.

Although the script works perfectly in my PC (XAMPP at Windows), in my Centos box it seems not work. After logging in, it keeps redirecting to the log in page (although the log in succeed).
Here is the code:

```
function request($url,$post)
{
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST           => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => '"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"',
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_REFERER => $url,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $post
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}
echo request('site.com/login.php',array("username" => "test", "password" => "test", "submit" => ""));
```

How would this code could be transfered to a working code in a Linux machine? What part am I missing?
Thank you very much,

Regards.

Comment: shouldn't need anything changed, since you're not using paths on the cookie file. as long as the UID this code is running under has the rights to create that file in the the script's working dir, then it should "just work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code was indeed perfect. All was needed is to create the file and give it the proper permissions.
Inspired by Marc B. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is concerned with the path to your cookie storage file. `'cookies.txt'` you using is a **relative** path. Relative paths works fine with internal PHP functions/extensions such as [Filesystem](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) functions. That's because they all have access to information about the current PHP script. But this is not always true for external extensions such as CURL. In most cases they doesn't know the location of the current PHP script (actually it depends on its installation) which results to relative paths (such as `'cookies.txt'`) doesn't work.

So the only way to ensure a path will work is to use **absolute** path. In order to obtain absolute path you can use [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__FILE__` or `__DIR__` (in PHP 5.3+):

```
$curlConfig = array(
    ...
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => dirname(__FILE__). '/cookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => dirname(__FILE__). '/cookies.txt',
    ...
);
```